# QtConcurrent with member function and thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I can run a member function in a separate thread using QtConcurrent::run. I use the following code:

```
QFuture<MyObject> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::doSomething, param1, param2);
```

Now I want to use a custom QThreadPool instead of the global one, as the number of threads for this task should be configurable. According to the documentation, I tried the following code, but unfortunately it can't find a fitting overload.

```
QThreadPool pool;
QFuture<MyObject> future = QtConcurrent::run(&pool, this, &MyClass::doSomething, param1, param2);
```

Is this supported?

Comment: which version of qt?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `QThreadPool` and `QtConcurrent` can't be mixed together

If you want to use a `QThreadPool`, you'll need to define an instance of `QRunnable`, which can call your function `MyClass::doSomething` in its `run()` function.

```
/* code not tested */
class RunnableHelper: public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT

    /* param1, param2 storage */

public:
    explicit RunnableHelper(param1, param2);

    void run()
    {
        MyClass::doSomething(param1, param2);
    }
};

RunnableHelper* rh= new RunnableHelper(param1, param2);
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(rh);
```